# how to stop default browser from opening the url twice in android

Tags: android

I have a simple application to open an url from the browser. It opens the url from the browse.but when the application is again opened then the background browser does not pop up instead the browser is again opened freshly. Such that there will be multiple instances in the background.. 
please help me how to stop opening the url from the browser if it is running in the resent app section.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        WebView m_cWebView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //      m_cWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WEB_VIEW);
    //      m_cWebView.loadUrl("http://209.198.193.73:9002/");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(android.net.Uri.parse("http://209.198.193.73:9002/"));
            this.startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well your `Activity` code states that upon creation, it should launch a browser and then `finish()` itself. So your Application only opens a browser. I guess resuming it will, normally, re-opens the browser.

Comment: yes, once the app will be opened and browser will be running in background. and again when i open the app then the app opens the url again from the same browser.. I wanted to stop opening it more than once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer because i finally found the solution for the above question. The commented webview lines shud be uncommented because i am using webview in that activity and also adding the below written code to reopen the next browsing url in the webview itself.

```
                    m_cWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                    m_cWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView pObjView, String pUrl) {
                            pObjView.loadUrl(pUrl);
                          return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String pUrl, Bitmap favicon) {
                            super.onPageStarted(view, pUrl, favicon);
                            }
                    });

                    m_cWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    m_cWebView.loadUrl(m_cLink);
```

This will solve the issue such that the next url does not open the default browser instead it gets opened in the webview itself.

Comment: Dear sachin, I need to do other side, i need to prevent going to the default browser, i am loading a asp web site to my web view, when press log in button the web view is requesting to go to the default browser. i need to stop it and going to the main form thought android web view. how do i fixed this please?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be able to provide a better experience by including a webview in you app, and displaying your url there. This will allow you more control, let you open external links with the browser, e.t.c.

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: I agree the point whatever u say but i wanted to know if there is any option  such as to stop opening the same url in the default browser more than once.. as u can see that i have commented the WebView part in my code